# Extracting data from notification database in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-notification

I was saved my notification into database like this:

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'from' => $this->message->name,
            'name'=> $this->message->email,
            'subject' => $this->message->subject,
            'body' => $this->message->body
        ];
    }
```

it work fine. Now i want to extract that data into my view, so i do like this:

```
@foreach ( Auth::user()->unreadNotifications as $notification)
                <li><!-- start message -->
                    <a href="#">
                        <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
                        <h4>
                            {{ $notification->name }}
                            <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                        </h4>
                        <!-- The message -->
                        <p>{{ $notification->subject }}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            @endforeach
```

but it give me nothing. so am i do it wrongly?

Comment: show us your unreadNotifications() method on users. Because i assume that is currently returning a empty collection? Or do you have a error message?

Comment: not it doesn't empty. i use {{ Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count() }} and it give me the number

Comment: unreadNotifications is part of Notifications function right?

Comment: Yes correct, sorry. What do you get when you do `@php dd($notification) @endphp` inside your foreach loop.

Comment: DatabaseNotificationCollection {#962 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => DatabaseNotification {#960 . it's too long i can't copy paste here.

Comment: but on #attributes: array:8 [▼
        "id" => "b456af82-3517-4803-95be-847a36fc4e41"
        "type" => "App\Notifications\MessageRecieved"
        "notifiable_id" => 1
        "notifiable_type" => "App\User"
        "data" => "{"from":ying cracker","name":"yingcracker@gmail.com","subject":"Ini adalah test.","body":"baik kita coba sent ya!!!"}"
        "read_at" => null
        "created_at" => "2017-12-05 11:03:27"
        "updated_at" => "2017-12-05 11:03:27"
      ]

Comment: ah it is inside a data object. So change {{ $notification->name}} to {{ $notification->data['name'] }}

Comment: nice it works. do you want to make it an aswer so i can choose it as the right answer? :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Noted from the comments The Notification object has a data attribute where all your data is stored so to access it:

change:

```
{{ $notification->name }}
```

to

```
{{ $notification->data['name'] }}
```

and do this for all your data.